# Python in Powershell, help(<module>) does not work

Tags: python, powershell, module

when in powershell I will import a module. (let's use sys as an example)

However when I type help(sys) it returns "'more' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

I did not even use the term 'more'. What is my issue?

Answer (score 0):

i think `less` is missing from your system

try:

```
sudo apt-get install less
```

then restart your python and try again